# Collecting the last updates of multiple tables into a single table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem in that I want my output to be a single table (lets call it Output) with 2 columns: one for the "TableName" and one for the DateTime of the last update (using the scn_to_timestamp(max(ora_rowscn)) command).

I have 100 tables and I want to pull in the last update date/times for all these tables into the Output table.

So I can do this:

```
insert into Output(TableName) 
select table_name
from all_tables;
```

which will put all the tables I have from my database into the TableName column. But I don't know how to loop through each entry and use the tablename as a variable and pass this into the scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn).

I thought I would try something like below:

```
for counter in Output(TableName) LOOP
insert into Output(UpdateDate)
select scn_to_timestamp(max(ora_rowscn)) 
from counter;
END LOOP;
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This query is a little bit clumsy as it uses `xmlgen` to execute dynamic sql in a query, but it might work for you.

```
select x.*  
  from all_tables t,       
       xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW' passing
            dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select ''' || t.table_name ||
                                   ''' tab_name, max(ora_rowscn) as la from ' ||
                                   t.table_name) 
                 COLUMNS tab_name  varchar2(30) PATH 'TAB_NAME',
                         max_scn number PATH 'LA') x
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2906d/2)

You can also use PLSQL and then use `execute immediate`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I don't really understand your query lol, but I plugged it into SQL Developer to see what the output would be like. Theres an error msg at the columns line saying "string literal required".

Comment: Then try running this command : `alter session set cursor_sharing=exact;`